# Vaadin with Spring and Redis loads previous UI state on slow environment

Tags: java, spring, serialization, redis, vaadin

I successfully enabled redis in a spring boot + vaadin application and it runs fine on my computer. The application is on a test run in a slower environment and an error occours multiple times.

```
WARN  c.v.s.communication.ServerRpcHandler [ServerRpcHandler.java : 266] - Unexpected message id from the client. Expected: 248, got: 249
```

It seems like it happens when the serialization/deserialization of the VaadinSession takes too long. For example I have a page that has multiple checkboxes. I click on the first, then the second and third. After this the upper warn is thrown and a previous state of the page appears. In this case it might be without any cheched checkboxes or with one or two checked checkboxes. In rare cases it works properly.

I can't think of a solution for the problem. One thing I tried is showing a loading indicator immediately (100ms) (the default is after 300ms of loading) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Can I somehow configure when the serialization/deserialization occurs instead of every UI change or make it faster by leaving parts of the VaadinSession out of it? (I need the data on the current page so I can't make the ui components transient.)

Answer (score 0):

We had a discussion about the problem in my workplace and we think that the components are working properly. The problem occurs when a serialization is slower then the next request's deserialization. (Every UI change begins with a deserialization to get the latest state then serializes the modified state.) My solution was creating an aspect that stores the latest VaadinSession that was sent for serialization and compares every deserialized VaadinSession to the stored one. I keep the one with the higher lastProcessedClientToServerId. This solves the issue almost every time.